# Cannot define a primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to define a primary key in a table using SQLAlchemy. The problem is that I can't do it due to the following error:

```
ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|BankAccount|bank_account could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'bank_account'
```

My code is this one:

```
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

# init app
app = Flask(__name__) 
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + 
os.path.join(basedir,'db.sqlite')

app.config ['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

# init db

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# init marshmallow
ma = Marshmallow(app)

# class account
class BankAccount(db.Model):
    number_acc: db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key = True)
    owner_acc: db.Column(db.String(50))
    bank: db.Column(db.String(50))
    amount_acc: db.Column(db.Float)

    # constructor of the class
   def __init__(self,number_acc,owner_acc,bank,amount_acc):
       self.number_acc = number_acc
       self.owner_acc = owner_acc
       self.bank = bank
       self.amount_acc = amount_acc
```

How can I insert the primary key in the table `bank_account`?

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy [`Column`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) objects are not type [annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), so you must assign them as class attributes instead – see ["Declaring a Mapping"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping) & ["Mapping Table Columns"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_columns.html):

```
class BankAccount(db.Model):
    number_acc = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key = True)
    owner_acc = db.Column(db.String(50))
    bank = db.Column(db.String(50))
    amount_acc = db.Column(db.Float)
```

In your current attempt you effectively have no columns that [Declarative](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/) can find during class construction, since the column information is hidden in the annotations.

Comment: I fixed the issue adding a line before attributes definititions as this one: __tablename__ = 'bankaccount'. I don't know why tablename is bold. Before and after tablename are two underscores

Comment: What issue? It is bold because double underscores add emphasis in comments.